# How to make a colspan and rowspan cell in asp.net without using <table> tag, only <div> tag

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have just switched toward  for using table format. If i want to do colspan and rowspan which we do in Table tag with  colspan & rowspan, how can we do the same in  tags. PLEASE HELP ME OUT.

Comment: There's no CSS equivalent of colspan and rowspan, but usually the effect you want can be achieved by other means. Please describe your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should  have  to learn/understand some of [CSS attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/) - `float`, `display`, `width`,`clear` etc.

For instance,

```
<style type="text/css">
 #leftPane{ 
  float:left;
  width:20%;
 }
 #rightPane{
  float:right;
  width:77%;
 }

<div id="leftPane"></div>
<div id="rightPane"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
....
```